# How to use fromEvent instead of bindCallback on an object method?

Tags: javascript, react-native, rxjs, rn-fetch-blob

I need to connect rn-fetch-blob's [onData](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/blob/ffc372e6e7f64ac77404549489557133ff4475f4/class/RNFetchBlobReadStream.js#L70) callback method to an observable.

As far as I know, this is not an event, [fromEventPattern](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/fromEventPattern) couldn't be used.
I can't see how to use [create](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/create.html) if this is the solution to my problem.

I have found [bindCallback](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/bindCallback#convert-jquery-s-getjson-to-an-observable-api) that looked promising, but the docs says that I probably should use fromEvent instead:

> Note that the Observable created by the output function will always emit a single value and then complete immediately. If func calls the callback multiple times, values from subsequent calls will not appear in the stream. If you need to listen for multiple calls, you probably want to use fromEvent or fromEventPattern instead.

I need to listen to multiple calls indeed.

Anyway I'm trying to use bindCallback on an object method as shown in the doc.
In my Typescript file:

```
import { bindCallback } from 'rxjs';
```

In my class:

```
private emitter!: Observable<any>;
```

in a private method:

```
RNFetchBlob.fs
    .readStream(
      filePath,
      "utf8",
      -1,
      10
    )
    .then(ifstream => {
      ifstream.open();
      this.emitter = bindCallback(ifstream.onData);
```

but it fails to compile:

```
error TS2322: Type '() => Observable<string | number[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type '() => Observable<string | number[]>'.
```

I really can't see how to use fromEvent in my case.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Added working code for those looking for the answer:

```
RNFetchBlob.fs
            .readStream(
              // file path
              peripheral.name,
              // encoding, should be one of `base64`, `utf8`, `ascii`
              "utf8",
              // (optional) buffer size, default to 4096 (4095 for BASE64 encoded data)
              // when reading file in BASE64 encoding, buffer size must be multiples of 3.
              -1,
              10
            )
            .then(ifstream => {
              ifstream.open();
              this.emitter = new Observable(subscriber => {
                ifstream.onData(chunk => {
                  // chunk will be a string when encoding is 'utf8'
                  logging.logWithTimestamp(`Received [${chunk}]`);
                  subscriber.next(chunk);
                });
                ifstream.onError(err => {
                  logging.logWithTimestamp(`oops [${err}]`);
                  subscriber.error(err);
                });

                ifstream.onEnd(() => {
                  subscriber.complete();
                });
              });
              this.rxSubscription = this.emitter
                .pipe(
                  concatMap(value =>
                    this.handleUpdatedValuesComingFromCSVFile(value)
                  )
                )
                .subscribe();
```

Comment: why not just use new Observable() constructor

Comment: @fancheung Yes that is the way to do it. Thank you so much for your help. Please add an answer for me to accept.

Comment: it is also possible to convert the entire promise to a single observable chain

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too familiar with `rn-fetch-blob` but hope you get the idea, also you return an function to run clean up logic.

```
 const onDataObserevable=new Obserevable(obs=>{
    ifstream.onData(data=>obs.next(data))
    return ()=>{... you can add some clean up logic here like unsubcribe from source onData event}
 });
```

> UPDATE

converted the whole chain to observable, hope you get the idea

```
from(RNFetchBlob.fs.readStream(
              peripheral.name,
              "utf8",
              -1,
              10
            ))
            .pipe(mergeMap(ifstream => {
              ifstream.open();
              return new Observable(subscriber => {
                ifstream.onData(chunk => {
                  // chunk will be a string when encoding is 'utf8'
                  logging.logWithTimestamp(`Received [${chunk}]`);
                  subscriber.next(chunk);
                });

                ifstream.onError(err => {
                  logging.logWithTimestamp(`oops [${err}]`);
                  subscriber.error(err);
                });

                ifstream.onEnd(() => {
                  subscriber.complete();
                });

              });),
              mergeMap(value =>this.handleUpdatedValuesComingFromCSVFile(value)
                  )
              )
```

Comment: I've added working code for you to see and comment if you like.

Comment: Ya that be great to see the true implementation

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with `fromEventPattern`:

```
this.emitter = fromEventPattern(
  // tell fromEventPattern how to subscribe to the data
  handler => ifstream.onData(handler),
  // tell fromEventPattern how to unsubscribe from the data
  handler => ifstream.onData(null)
)
```

Comment: I've tried @fanchung suggestion to use the Observable() constructor and  made it work just before you answered. You both deserve an accepted answer :(